# Splitting NSString not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, split

I have seen may topics that talk about that but none of them has been useful for me. I am trying to parse GEORSS and the coordinates are given me with the following format:

```
<georss:point>4613618.31000115 676474.87007986</georss:point>
```

So I have tried to split it into an NSArray and then assign them to the corresponding XML key, but it always crash with that error:

2013-04-02 12:33:11.234 GeoRss1[2125:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:

(0x1959012 0x1275e7e 0x18fb0b4 0x19d23a8 0x3f48 0xd55a37 0x1c96600 0x1ca1a2b 0x1ca0f07 0xd53e02 0x34b8 0xd7b589 0xd79652 0xd7a89a 0xd7960d 0xd79785 0xcc6a68 0x14a1911 0x14a0bb3 0x14decda 0x18fb8fd 0x14df35c 0x14df2d5 0x13c9250 0x18dcf3f 0x18dc96f 0x18ff734 0x18fef44 0x18fee1b 0x18b37e3 0x18b3668 0x1b9ffc 0x1ddd 0x1d05)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    }else if([elemAct isEqualToString:@"georss:point"]){

        componentes = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
        if ( componentes != nil){

            [xmlLat appendString:componentes[0]];
            [xmlLon appendString:componentes[1]];
        }
     ...
 ...
```

In the header of that file I have declares both variables correctly and the synthesized them:

```
...    
@property (strong) NSMutableString *xmlLat; 
@property (strong) NSMutableString *xmlLon;
...
```

Thank you everyone for advanced, you already have helped me with some responses in other topics!

Comment: can you try to NSLog string before  componentes = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy]; this line.

Comment: Along with above comment, Replace "componentes != nil" with "componentes.count == 2" and check the result..

Comment: Still crashes @BhanuPrakash :/

Answer (score 1):

I tried following code :

```
NSString *abc = @"4613618.31000115 676474.87007986";
NSArray *componentes = [[abc componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"componentes : %@",componentes);

NSMutableString *xmlLat = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""];
NSMutableString *xmlLon = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""];

[xmlLat appendString:componentes[0]];
[xmlLon appendString:componentes[1]];

NSLog(@"xmlLat : %@",xmlLat);
NSLog(@"xmlLon : %@",xmlLon);
```

It worked perfectly for me. I thin the problem is you are not getting proper data in your string.

Comment: Well, I have debugged it and the data seems to be ok, the problem appears when assigning it to the XML Keys:

componentes NSArray * 0x0845e820
[0] id 0x0845e6d0 @"4613618.31000115"
[1] id 0x0845e800 @"676474.87007986"

 //// I try what you say and come back to answer in a few mins

Comment: @rushi: You tried with string that is straight forward simple. He has some other problem with xml and may be some other objects too.

Comment: Using NSString *abc = @"4613618.31000115 676474.87007986"; it works fine, how can I make it read well the String that I am parsing? Any idea of where the error can be?

Comment: @user1831622: use NSLog(@"%@",[string class]), to see what class is it

Comment: @user1831622 an you try to NSLog string before componentes = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy]; this line. And paste here what it gives.

Comment: Thats what it prints: (Thank you everyone :)) 2013-04-02 13:32:22.546 GeoRss1[2429:c07] componentes : (
    "4613618.31000115",
    "676474.87007986"
)
2013-04-02 13:32:22.547 GeoRss1[2429:c07] __NSCFString
(lldb)

Comment: Try to place log for string also, like Anoop said.

Comment: Can this error is possible coz you have not initialized your NSMutableString

Comment: Sorry @Rushi, my mistake. What it shows is: 2013-04-02 13:48:13.734 GeoRss1[2505:c07] componentes : (null)
(lldb)

Comment: @Rushi if you mean the Lat and Long, they are inizializated here: self.xmlLat = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.xmlLon = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; if you want me to paste more code just say it :)

Comment: @user1831622 so you are getting the crash coz you are not getting proper data. You'll have to check your data.